# Handling multiple queries in C#

Tags: c#

In my project I am using 10-15 SQL queries, for that I have a common `class` for **database connectivity** and using that I have executed the queries by passing the `connection`, `command` and `dataReader`.

With some reference in SO, I learned that my code is not properly structured.  I would like to learn and write high performance code.

**DBConnectivity.cs**:

```
class DBConnectivity
    {
        public SqlConnection connection = null;
        public SqlCommand command = null;
        public SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
        public string connectionString = null;
        public List<MasterTableAttributes> masterTableList;
        public DBConnectivity()
        {
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());

            //-----Master table results 
            connection.Open();
            string masterSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_TABLE";
            command = new SqlCommand(masterSelectQuery, connection);
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            masterTableList = new List<MasterTableAttributes>();

            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                MasterTableAttributes masterTableAttribute = new MasterTableAttributes()
                {
                    fileId = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["Id"]),
                    fileName = Convert.ToString(dataReader["FileName"]),
                    frequency = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Frequency"]),
                    scheduledTime = Convert.ToString(dataReader["Scheduled_Time"])
                };
                masterTableList.Add(masterTableAttribute);
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Program.cs**:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                DBConnectivity dbConnectivity = new DBConnectivity();                   
                Transaction txnObj = new Transaction(dbConnectivity); //Query1
                Sales saleObj = new Sales (dbConnectivity);//Query2
           }
    }
```

**Transaction.cs**:

```
class Transaction
    {    
        public Transaction(DBConnectivity dbConnectivity)
        {            
            dbConnectivity.connection.Open();
            string txnQuery = "SELECT ...";

            dbConnectivity.command = new SqlCommand(txnQuery, dbConnectivity.connection);

            dbConnectivity.dataReader = dbConnectivity.command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dbConnectivity.dataReader.Read())
            {
                ...
            }
            dbConnectivity.dataReder.close();
            dbConnectivity.connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

**Sales.cs**:

```
class Sales
    {    
        public Sales(DBConnectivity dbConnectivity)
        {            
            dbConnectivity.connection.Open();
            string salesQuery = "SELECT ...";

            dbConnectivity.command = new SqlCommand(salesQuery, dbConnectivity.connection);

            dbConnectivity.dataReader = dbConnectivity.command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dbConnectivity.dataReader.Read())
            {
                ...
            }
            dbConnectivity.dataReder.close();
            dbConnectivity.connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reader/command/connection fields of `DBConnectivity` are not really being used to represent state of `DBConnectivity`. This is obvious because of usage like:

```
dbConnectivity.command = new SqlCommand(salesQuery, dbConnectivity.connection);
dbConnectivity.dataReader = dbConnectivity.command.ExecuteReader();
while (dbConnectivity.dataReader.Read()) {...}
```

frankly, they should just be local variables:

```
var command = new SqlCommand(salesQuery, connection);
var dataReader = dbConnectivity.command.ExecuteReader();
while (dataReader.Read()) {...}
```

---

Additionally, in all uses, you are not correctly disposing your resources. The `IDisposable` contract is important: if something is `IDisposable`, then it is **your job** to make sure it gets disposed when done. So with the above example:

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand(salesQuery, connection))
using(var dataReader = dbConnectivity.command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dataReader.Read()) {...}
}
```

This `using` makes a **huge** difference, and ensures you don't drop connections etc on the floor when exceptions happen.

---

Personally, I would not advocate doing this type of work *in a constructor* - that is not intuitive. A `static` method that returns a populated instance, sure - or an instance method that populates an existing instance. But a constructor? not so clear.

---

I also suspect that you could benefit from the use of tooling to avoid boiler-plate code that is error-prone and not important to your actual work. For example, tools like dapper allow much simpler object population. For example:

```
public class DBConnectivity
{
    private readonly string connectionString;
    public DBConnectivity(string connectionString = null)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Master"].ConnectionString;
        }
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }
    public SqlConnection OpenConnection() {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        conn.Open();
        return conn;
    }
    public List<MasterTableAttributes> GetMasterTableList()
    {
        using(var connection = OpenConnection())
        {
            const string sql = "SELECT Id as [FileId], FileName, Frequency, Scheduled_Time as [ScheduledTime] FROM MASTER_TABLE";
            return connection.Query<MasterTableAttributes>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Here the only useful state is the connection string, with a method that creates new connections. Note how this is used with `using` to create **and dispose** the connection, with "dapper" then taking the load for handling the data.

If you really wanted to pass this around, you can:

```
    public List<SomethingSalesEsque> SomeMethodOnSales(DBConnectivity dbConnectivity)
    {            
        using(var conn = dbConnectivity.OpenConnection())
        {
            return conn.Query<SomethingSalesEsque>(someQuery).ToList();
        }
    }
```

---

From your code, I'm *guessing* you have:

```
class MasterTableAttributes
{
    public int fileId;
    public string fileName;
    public string frequency;
    public string scheduledTime;
}
```

this would preferably be:

```
class MasterTableAttributes
{
    public int FileId {get;set;}
    public string FileName {get;set;}
    public string Frequency {get;set;} // maybe an enum?
    public string ScheduledTime {get;set;} // datetime? timespan?
}
```

Comment: I tried using **Dapper.net** tool from **NuGet** package, while debugging I was redirected to a new tab `"No Source Available"`.  Is there anything I am missing and will this cause any problem further?

Comment: @user1671639 presumably there was an exception: if so - what was the exception message? it is *probably* trying hard to tell you what the problem is. You can see the exception when debugging in the IDE, or by using `catch`.

Comment: there is no exception. But when I tried to debug it took to a new tab saying **"No Source Available"** where the `stacktrace` message of `SqlMapper.cs` took place.

Comment: @user1671639 for it to do that, either there *is* an exception, or you are hitting "step into". If the latter: well, don't "step into" if there is nothing to step into. If the former: try just hitting the "play" button (F5) to see what it says next. Can you clarify what you mean by "the `stacktrace` message" ?

Comment: Yeah this happens only when I hit "stepInto".  Sorry that is not `stacktrace` it is **"Call stack location"**.  Would be helpful If there are tutorials in `dapper.net`.

Comment: @user1671639 there really isn't much more to it than on the homepage: https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/